# recursive function not working correct?

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, dom, recursion

I've created a function "[Query-ComDomElements.ps1](https://github.com/gpunktschmitz/Query-ComDomElements.ps1)" to query HTML objects.

This works quite well when querying only one object and querying that again.

When I try calling it in recursion it however fails and I don't understand why. The code/objects is/are the very same.

Could anyone please enlighten me why the query `.container>img` is not working, but querying `.container` and with that `img` is?

The error I get when querying both (and thus calling the function recursively) is:

> ```
> Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"
> At C:\path\to\Query-ComDomElements.ps1:31 char:5
> + ...             $result = [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("getElementsB ...
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException
> ```

Here my sample script (function `Query-ComDomElements.ps1` not included but on [github](https://github.com/gpunktschmitz/Query-ComDomElements.ps1)):

```
. C:\path\to\Query-ComDomElements.ps1

$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

$ie.Navigate2("https://www.gpunktschmitz.de/")

while($ie.Busy) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}


#this works
$imgContainer = Query-ComDomElements -Query '.container' -Dom $ie.Document
$image = Query-ComDomElements -Query 'img' -Dom $imgContainer -Property 'src'

#this fails
$image = Query-ComDomElements -Query '.container>img' -Dom $ie.Document -Property 'src'

$ie.quit()
```

Comment: In what way does it fail? Do you get an error message or just some unexpected or null result?

Comment: hi Mark, I've updated the question with the error/exception I get.

Comment: That file on github is not that long and would be fine to include in the question. It should be included here since the question is useless without it.

Comment: What $dom is returning? A single entity or an array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is occurring because `$dom` ends up being an array with two elements when it is passed in on the second iteration. One (dirty) fix for this would be to use `Select-Object` to just get the first element (suggest using `Select` rather than `[0]` so that if its not an array it doesn't error):

```
if($SecondQuery -eq $false) {
    if($Property -ne $false -and $Property -ne '*') {
        return $result.$Property
    } else {
        return $result
    }
} else {
    return Query-ComDomElements -Query $SecondQuery -Dom ($result | select -first 1) -Property $Property
}
```

Comment: I still get the error with the modifications you suggested. Did the example work for you with these changes? If so, which OS and PSVersion are you using?

Comment: No I'm not able to test it as I can't find a site to query that mirrors yours. This just seemed like a likely candidate based on the way the logic was operating.

Comment: I think the issue is because $dom ends up being an array with two elements when it goes in to the second iteration. You can do `return Query-ComDomElements -Query $SecondQuery -Dom ($Result | Select -First 1) -Property $Property` and it works.

Comment: Hi Mark, you may use the code above and query my site (no need for mirrors). the content of `$result` is one object of type `System.__ComObject` and not an array. I also tested your suggestions with no luck.

Comment: Weird, my fix worked when I tested it and I was doing it against your site in the end.

Comment: My bad. Your `| Select -First 1)` fix works (now) for whatever reason it didn't yesterday ... Thanks!